# Recursion $y_n = ky_{n-1}+ry_{n-2}, y_0 = 2, y_1 = k$ and Fermat Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, recursion

I was looking for the 
$$y_n = ky_{n-1}+ry_{n-2},\\ y_0 = 2,\\ y_1 = k$$ 
recursive relation and according Diophantine equations  $y_n=z^2$. Then I saw that for the $$k=A+B\\ r=-AB \\ y_n=A^n+B^n$$

So if we look for $y_n=Z^n$ this is equivalent to Fermat Theorem.

I did some investigation and there can be a way to go deeper. But I was unable to find any paper about this method. So my question is if there is any paper or may be any idea about the method investigating/solving the Diophantine equations based on general recursive relation, which is:

$$y_n = ky_{n-1}+ry_{n-2}$$

EDITED

Here we were talking about the integer A and B numbers, but if A and B are rational, then the Fermat Last Theorem can be rephrased as $$y_n=1$$
can not take place for $n>2$.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A method to resolve linear recurrences?

Comment: Nope. I am looking for the method investigating the diophantine equations based on general recursive relation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, [here is a paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m105f12/public_html/lucaHungary1.pdf) on Diophantine equations and sections 2.1.2/2.1.3 show links between binary recurrences and Pell's equations. But, and this is important, those recurrences rely on **the minimal solution in positive integers**.

In this particular case, using [characteristic polynomial](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) method to solve linear recurrences
$$y^2=ky+r \Leftrightarrow y^2-ky-r=0$$
$$\color{red}{y_{1}=}\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2} \text{ and } \color{red}{y_{2}=}\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2}$$
So general solution is
$$y_n=C_1 y_1^n+C_2 y_2^n$$
where
$$2=C_1 + C_2$$
$$k=C_1 y_1+C_2 y_2=\\
C_1 \frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2}+C_2 \frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2}=\\
\frac{C_1 k-C_1 \sqrt{k^2+4r}+C_2 k+C_2\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2}=\\
\frac{2k -C_1 \sqrt{k^2+4r} + C_2\sqrt{k^2+4r}}{2}$$
leading to $$C_1=C_2=1$$
and the final solution is
$$y_n=y_1^n+y_2^n$$
The trick with $k=A+B, r=-AB$ works as well, leading to $y_n=A^n+B^n$ as you pointed out, so far so good. But, will you find **the minimal solution in positive integers**, given Fermat's Last Theorem was proved?

Comment: The paper you pointed is really useful, many thanks. Actually I am trying to understand why $y_n=z^n$ can not take place from recursion point of view. I am sure that this is probably not as simple, but this is at least will allow to understand some details about the diophantine equations.