# Exercises about closed form formula of recursive sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, closed-form

I've searched on web some exercises about closed form formula of recursive sequence, but I have not found more difficult ones. For example the majority of them ask me to find close form formula for $a_n$, so I'm wondering if there are other ones that ask me for $a_{2n}$ or something similar. Furthermore the types of exercises that I'm looking for concerns linear sequence like these:

1. $a_n = 3a_{n-1} +2$
2. $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}$

---

Someone of you know where I can find exercises like these?
Thanks.

Comment: You could always try examples in Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics*.

Comment: Google for 1) generating functions 2) homogeneous recurrence sequences and 3) characteristic polynomials

Comment: Or look at some other example like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547762/recursion-y-n-ky-n-1ry-n-2-y-0-2-y-1-k-and-fermat-theorem/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559687/show-that-the-sequence-a-1-1-a-2-2-a-n2-a-n1a-n-2-converges-b/