# Verification (and help) with the questions related to convergence of recurrences in the form $x_{n+2} = kx_{n+1} + px_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

> Given $x_1 = a$ and $x_2 = b$ find the values of $a, b \in \Bbb R, n\in\Bbb N$ for which the following recurrences converge (diverge):
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> x_{n+2} &= 2x_{n+1} - x_n \tag1\\
> x_{n+2} &= 4x_{n+1} - 3x_n\tag2\\
> x_{n+2} &= -2x_{n+1} - x_n\tag3\\
> x_{n+2} &= x_{n+1} + 2x_n\tag4\\
> \end{align*}
> $$

---

$(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} &= 2x_{n+1} - x_n \iff \\
x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} &= x_{n+1} - x_n = \\
&= x_{n+1} - x_{n}\\ 
&= x_{n} - x_{n-1}\\
&\cdots\\
&= x_{2} - x_{1}\\
&= b - a
\end{align}
$$
Now taking the limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(a-b)=a-b
$$
For this recurrence to be convergent $a$ must be equal to $b$, otherwise it doesn't satisfy Cauchy criteria, thus:
$$
a = b \implies \exists \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \\
a \ne b \implies \exists! \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n
$$

---

$(2)$:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} &= 4x_{n+1} - 3x_n \iff\\
x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} &= 3(x_{n+1} - x_n) \\
&= 3^2(x_{n} - x_{n-1})\\
&\cdots \\
&= 3^{n-1}(x_{2} - x_{1})\\
&= 3^{n-1}(b - a)
\end{align}
$$

This case is similar to $(1)$:
$$
b = a \implies \exists \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\\
b \ne a \implies \exists! \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n
$$

---

$(3)$:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} &= -2x_{n+1} - x_n \iff \\
x_{n+2} + x_{n+1} &= -(x_{n+1} + x_n) \\
&= (x_{n} + x_{n-1}) \\
&= -(x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}) \\
&\cdots\\
&= (-1)^{n-1}(x_2 + x_1) \\
&= (-1)^{n-1}(b + a) \\
\end{align}
$$

In this case convergence is only possible if:
$$
a + b = 0 \implies \exists \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\\
a + b \ne 0 \implies \exists! \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n
$$

---

$(4)$. I'm stuck with this one, not sure what transformations to apply. I could probably use generating functions or solve through a characteristic polynomial, but that is heavy machinery for such a simple case. I would also like to not apply any solutions involving matrices since i'm not very familiar with linear algebra yet.

> Could you please verify the first three cases and either suggest a solution or give a hint for the last one? Thank you!

Comment: how $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{n+1} -x_n|=0 $ will ensure that limit of sequence will exist ?

Comment: @neelkanth well, it might not, i'm not sure. However if we choose some $C\in\Bbb R^+$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| = |a - b| \le C\lambda^n$ then $x_n$ converges. And this seems to only be possible for $a-b = 0$

Comment: You could have tried characteristic polynomial method indeed, e.g. very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547762/recursion-y-n-ky-n-1ry-n-2-y-0-2-y-1-k-and-fermat-theorem/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two points are correct (but you need to justify $a= b \implies (x_n) \text{ is convergent}$).

For the third point $x_{n+1}+x_n=0$ for all $n$ does not ensure that $(x_n)$ is convergent. In fact it leads to $x_{n+1}=-x_n$ so
$$x_n=(-1)^{n-1} a = (-1)^{n-2} b$$
so the condition is $a+b=0 \text{ and } a=b=0$.

For the last point in you want to applies a similar method the best way is to define
$$y_{n}=x_{n+1}+\lambda x_n$$
where $\lambda$ is *a parameter we will choose later*.

In this case we have
$$y_{n+1}=x_{n+2}+\lambda x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}+2x_n+\lambda x_{n+1}\\=(1+\lambda)\left(x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{1+\lambda} x_n \right).$$

So by *choosing $\lambda$* such that $2/(1+\lambda)=\lambda$ i.e $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-2$ we obtain

- $\lambda=1$

$$(x_{n+2}+x_{n+1})=2(x_{n+1}+x_n)$$

- $\lambda=-2$

$$(x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1})=-(x_{n+1}-2x_n)$$

so you obtain a necessary condition for convergence
$$b+a=0$$
$$b-2a=0$$
and so the sequence is convergent iff $a=b=0$.

---

Note that by considering a generic recurrence  you can show that the good choice of $\lambda$ are always the opposite of the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Nice approach for the last case. Thank you!