# Solving the recurrence relation $f(n) = k f(n-1) - f(n-2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let us assume that $k$, $f(1)$, and $f(0)$ are constants. I am trying to find a closed form expression for $f(a)$, $a >= 2$ in terms of $k$, $f(1)$, and $f(0)$. I have to tried to recursively substitute values for $f(a)$ to try and generate a pattern.
\begin{eqnarray}
f(2) &=& k f(1) - f(0) \newline
f(3) &=& (k^{2}-1) f(1) - k f(0) \newline
f(4) &=& k(k^{2}-3) f(1) - (k^{2}-1) f(0) \newline
f(5) &=& (k^{4}-3k^{2}+1) f(1) - k(k^{2}-2) f(0)
\end{eqnarray}
However, this is perhaps not the right way to approach this problem, and I'm looking for alternative ways to solve it?

Comment: it will be $f(n)=Ca^n+Db^n$ where $a$ and $b$ are roots of $x^2-kx+1=0$; cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547762/recursion-y-n-ky-n-1ry-n-2-y-0-2-y-1-k-and-fermat-theorem/2548686#2548686) is an example you could use

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I solved the recurrence relation using your approach. Thanks!